# How to make primitive type reference for binding

Tags: angular

Before, I know it is kind of stupid question but i'm interested of finding answer (Don't vote down :))

I used to have this problem with angularJS and now I'm learning angular 6 and hoped there is a solution for it (which I haven't found yet)

I've created 2 custom components. The father gets an object for binding and gives its property to the son component.

For ex.

**Son Component**

```
<div>{{ value }}</div>
```

**Father Component**

```
<div>
   <son-component [value]="config.configSonValue"></son-component>
</div>
```

**Usage of Father**

```
<father-component [config]="myConfig"></father-component>
```

I'm skipping the code because it is not relevant to the question.

This is the `myConfig` value

```
this.sonValue = 1;
const myConfig = {
   configSonValue: this.sonValue // This line is the problem - loosing the reference
}
```

This makes the application run and show the `1`.
But if i'm changing the value in my `this.sonValue` is not affecting the UI.

It makes sense cause the moment i'm setting the value of `configSonValue` the value from `this.sonValue` is being copied and not referenced while its primitive type.

Today i'm asking the user to provide me the scope object and the **name** of the variable he wants to bind.. and in the binding i'm doing `scope[name]`.

I hoped there is something like

```
const myConfig = {
   configSonValue: angular.copyRef(this.sonValue) // wishful solution 
}
```

Here is an example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2ta9ug

Is there ?

Comment: Can you post an example showing your problem? The value *should* update.

Comment: If i'm changing the `this.sonValue` it is not updating the value of `myConfig.configSonValue`.. cause they are 2 different variables now.. It is more js question then angular actually.. Do you still want me to create some demo for it ?

Comment: You're not binding to a primitive, you're binding to a component prop. It's bound by reference. So yeah, demo would help.

Comment: I've added the example link to the post

Comment: Well, I guess I was wrong. You could wrap your primitive in object and then it will be passed by reference. I don't know about any `copyReference` or like  method in Ng2

Comment: _Well, I guess I was wrong_ It happens to the best... I don't want my users to wrap their scope primitives in objects in order to use me... so i came up with the `scope` and `variable name` solution.. but i still don't really like it